# How do I add multiple values to a "if" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if value is not the write word. 
I basically want to do this:

```
test = input("Place input here")

if test == "a", "A", "A.", etc. 
   print("You have no life!")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `in` like this:

```
if test in ["a", "A", "A."]:
```